# Add class to ALL matching parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, this seems simple but I am not able to solve it for some hours.

Following are four `div.testName`, what I want is:
if `div.testName` contains child `div#wrong` then it must add class `wrongParent` to that specific parent. 
Similarly, if `div.testName` contains child `div#right` then it must add class `rightParent` to that specific parent.

Now if there are 3 `div#wrong` then 3 `div.testName` must also have 3 `wrongParent` assigned to them one for each `div`.

I have created fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/farazi482/aLd9w97s/6/)

Please help

```js
$( "#right" ).each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('rightParent');
    $('<span>i m right</span>').insertBefore('.testName .head > h3');
});         
$( "#wrong" ).each(function() {
    $(this).parent().addClass('wrongParent');
    $('<span>i m wrong</span>').insertBefore('.testName .head > h3');
});
```

```html
<div class="testName">
    <div class="head">
        <h3>wrong heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="wrong"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="testName">
     <div class="head">
         <h3>wrong heading</h3>
     </div>
     <div id="wrong"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="testName">
     <div class="head">
         <h3>right heading</h3>
     </div>
     <div id="right"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="testName">
     <div class="head">
         <h3>right heading</h3>
     </div>
     <div id="right"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: `id` should be unique . Use `class` for that

Comment: You could use the attribute-selector for this: [`$( "div[id='right'" )`](https://jsfiddle.net/aLd9w97s/9/) but I would definitly not recommend doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `id` to `class`

```js
$( ".right" ).each(function( ) {
 $(this).parent().addClass('rightParent');
 $('<span>i m right</span>').insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
   
$( ".wrong" ).each(function( ) {
 $(this).parent().addClass('wrongParent');
 $('<span>i m wrong</span>').insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

```css
.testName { 
  width:90%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  border: solid 4px grey;
}
.rightParent {
  border: solid 4px green;
}
.wrongParent {
  border: solid 4px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testName">
    <div class="head">
      <h3>wrong heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="wrong">
    </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="testName">
    <div class="head">
      <h3>wrong heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="wrong">
    </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="testName">
    <div class="head">
      <h3>right heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="testName">
    <div class="head">
      <h3>right heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: one question, this phrase "i m righti m righti m wrongi m wrong" is repeating. is it possible to have it show only once in each div according to rightParent or wrongParent?